# Is there a stencil package that works out of the box with express template rendering?

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, stenciljs

I've tried (and failed) to use 3 different Stencil packages with node/express. (stencil, stencil-js, @stencil). In particular, I am looking for a package that lets me do the standard express template rendering, like:

```
npm install stencil

.
.
app.engine('stencil', require('stencil').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'stencil');

.
.
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // Where 'somepage' is /views/somepage.stencil
    res.render('somepage', { title: 'Stencil Test' });
});
```

The packages I tried seem to be for some other purpose, i.e. there isn't a `render` function and/or a callback method that you would use with the app.engine() function. I'm probably overlooking the obvious as Stencil seems to be popular (kitura, etc) and would seem to be a natural fit with express.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm from what you are saying maybe you are looking for SSR(Server Side Rendering)?

You have an example on how to render your page on the server with Express

```
const express = require('express');
const stencil = require('@stencil/core/server');

// create the express app
const app = express();

// load the stencil config and
// express serve-side rendering middleware
const { wwwDir, logger } = stencil.initApp({
  app: app,
  configPath: __dirname
});

// serve static files
app.use(express.static(wwwDir));

// set which port express it will be listening on
const port = 3030;

// start listening and handling requests
app.listen(port, () => logger.info(`server-side rendering listening on port: ${ port }`));
```

You can find more information about SSR [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/server-side-rendering)